# Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE

Tags: grub2, kernel

Using 14.04, I have the following error displayed when booting up:

> Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE

It doesn't cause any problems with the system, but I would still like to remove it. Now, I managed to do this in the past by editing the GRUB config, but I cannot for the life of me remember what parameter I added. I've looked at the kernel options listed in 'Boot Repair' and none of them ring a bell. I don't want break my system by willy nilly testing each.

I previously found the solution on a message board, but googling for the term hasn't yielded the result I was hoping for. If I remember correctly, it was related to the kernel probing for an AGP card whereas I use a PCI-E card. I know the error relates to key mapping, but I never changed anything related to the keyboard.

Here is my full [dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jSHBTw9a)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue, I looked out in the intenet and I found this web page:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250210

Take a look, maybe it helps you, however I didn't try the solution in that page.

Comment: so just remove all the things? that forum post is not very clear on what to do... OP, did you solve it on your machine? please post answer if so.

Comment: @Mohammad I never solved it, but, it went away after getting a new keyboard/mouse. So, I guess you were on track to the solution. If it helps anybody, I was using the Logitech Wave Pro package, now I'm using the Logitech k800.

Comment: @Waldermort a few minutes ago I updated my kernel to 4.0 and guess what?! the error message has been disappeard from boot screen. give it a shot